# Custom ui:widget will not alter the formData

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

When using `ui:widget` the field will not change the `formData` of the form, unlike when not using `ui:widget` any change in the field will be seen in the `formData` when the form is submitted.

Shall I change the `formData` of the form manually when the field text changes? if so, is there an example to do so?

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create the class that represent the custom UI, and use the following for render:

`return (
      <div >
      {this.props.children}

      </div>
    )`

2. Add to the `schema.properties` `"City": {type: "string", title:"City"}`
3. Add to the `schema.properties` `"City": { "ui:widget": DefaultInput, classNames: "col-md-4"}`

Where `City` is the name of the custom component.
and `DefaultInput` is the class that represent the custom ui of field.

Expected behavior

To see the value of the custom text field when submit the form:

`onSubmit = ({formData}) => console.log(formData);`

What I see is:

`{City: undefined}`

Any idea?

Comment: You should hand down react-jsonschema-form's (FieldProps, if you are using typescript) onChange inside DefaultInput to the actual input field. Showing how you defined DefaultInput would be great.

Answer (score 1):

if you use custom 'ui:widgets' you have to use the json-schema-form onChange method when any item's value gets changed and after that you can get changed value from form.